# D3 graphs Multi series with different time range not working properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

Please find below fiddle-link.
     https://jsfiddle.net/zwb1hbdz/1/

```
[https://jsfiddle.net/zwb1hbdz/1/][1]
```

Range for line is time  date: "08:45" to  date: "08:54"
And for line 2 date: "08:44", to date: "08:53" so creates issue with second line?

how can i set dynamic time range from "08:44" to "08:54"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to sort your data in order of time. I've adjusted your parse function to match how it's stored, then used the array sort method:

```
var parse = d3.time.format("%H:%M").parse;

data = data.sort(function(a,b) {
    return parse(a.date) - parse(b.date);
} );
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/zwb1hbdz/2/